# Automatic internationalization in Java

Tags: java, swing, internationalization

I have an issue with automatic internationalization in java, using netbeans. In actionListener I am chaging locale with this:

```
String s = (String)langBox.getSelectedItem();
switch(s){
    case "Čeština":
        BP_evolution.language = "cs";
        BP_evolution.currentLocale = new Locale(BP_evolution.language);
        break;
    case "English":
        BP_evolution.language = "en";
        BP_evolution.currentLocale = new Locale(BP_evolution.language);
        break;
}
```

Actually, the issue is, that I don't know what function should I call for switching language in my application. I am using Java SE and Swing. Like I already said, ResourceBundle has been created automatically.

Comment: but nothing in your post, nor code posted here talking about ... , code examples aroud us about ResourceBundle + Locale  + i18/ResourceBundle + Locale works by default

Comment: I am just asking what to add into this code to switch the language.. I guess that it should be correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue with this has been resolved by SwingWorkers. When I put the function of switching languages, it started to work.

You can read about it here -> [java doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html)

Problem was probably that main thread stucked with running GUI itself and it was not able to do anything else.